# fade in fade out on hover in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create component in react. I am on learning mode. So may be I am doing totally wrong. Below is my code

`My Code on sandbx`

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-bush-roiv6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
class MegaMenu extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.MegaMenu}>
        <div className={styles["menu-container"]}>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <MenuList Options={menus} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        props.Options.map((Option: IMenu, index: number) => (
          <li key={index} className={(Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) ? styles["menu-dropdown-icon"] : styles["normal-sub"]}>
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I was trying something as in jQuery if like have children

```
$(".menu > ul > li").hover(
        function (e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 943) {
                $(this).children("ul").fadeIn(150);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }, function (e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 943) {
                $(this).children("ul").fadeOut(150);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    );
```

How we can do in react.

Comment: Your codesandbox link isn't working for me. The sandbox loads but the page on the right side is just empty, white

Comment: Can you just clarify something for me? You want to do something in react which causes an element, when it is hovered over, to transition to `opacity:0` and then, at the end, to `display:none`

Comment: @TKoL just open in separate window or increase size of the right side of preview it will start showing

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer solving your problem, just some direction you might want to take:

What I would do is make `<MenuList>` a stateful component rather than functional, and store a bit of state about whether it was being hovered or not. On the `<ul>` do an `onMouseEnter` callback that sets the hovered state and an `onMouseLeave` callback that unsets it (sets it to false), and pass down a prop to the next `MenuList` about if it should show or not.

You can choose a variety of options to deal with that prop. If animation isn't necessary, you can simply add a `style` property to the `ul` if the `props.show === true`:

```
let styles = {};
if (this.props.show) {
  styles = {display:block}
}
...
<ul style={styles}>
...
```

If animation is required... well then good luck.